# How to I shorten this base64 line by 4 characters?

Tags: encoding, binary, base64

i'm working on a geometry dash private server and I need to replace the original database link (aHR0cDovL3d3dy5ib29tbGluZ3MuY29tL2RhdGFiYXNl) with my own but every time I encode my database link it results in a string that is 4 characters longer (aHR0cHM6Ly9nb29kY2F0cHMuNnRlLm5ldC9kYXRhYmFzZQ==) and the game doesn't run when I replace the strings.

I've tried removing the last 4 characters but the game still doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, your input string (`https://goodcatps.6te.net/database`) is longer than the original one (`http://www.boomlings.com/database`). base64 is a just a different encoding of your characters, it doesn't do any compression (but it might add some extra padding bytes). therefore the longer your input string, the longer the base64 encoded output.

so in order to shorten the base64 encoded string, you must shorten your input string, thus get a new (shorter) URL for your database.

Comment: Yeah turns out I had the start as https:// not http://